# Compiler wont tell what struct field is not satisfying a trait bound

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm having trouble implementing a struct to load data from a table. I understand that the error is telling me that the trait bounds are not satisfied to load the data but it wont tell specifically what field in the struct is problematic. I already check the docs and the types seems correct. What process would I take to identify the problematic field since the compiler wont be specific?

I have this table (generated by diesel):

```
diesel::table! {
    product (id) {
        id -> Varchar,
        title -> Varchar,
        visible -> Tinyint,
        description -> Varchar,
        section -> Varchar,
        price -> Decimal,
        discount -> Decimal,
        isFeatured -> Tinyint,
        availableQuantity -> Nullable<Integer>,
        createdAt -> Datetime,
        updatedAt -> Datetime,
        category_id -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

This is the struct to load data:

```
#[derive(Queryable, Clone, Identifiable, Associations, Debug)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(ProductCategory, foreign_key = category_id))]
#[diesel(table_name = product)]
pub struct Product {
    pub id: String,                      //diesel::sql_types::Text / id -> Varchar
    pub title: String,                   //diesel::sql_types::Text / title -> Varchar
    pub visible: i8,                     //TinyInt / visible -> Tinyint
    pub description: String,             //diesel::sql_types::Text / description -> Varchar
    pub section: String,                 //diesel::sql_types::Text / section -> Varchar
    pub price: BigDecimal,               //diesel::sql_types::Numeric / price -> Decimal
    pub discount: BigDecimal,            //diesel::sql_types::Numeric / discount -> Decimal
    pub is_featured: i8,                 //TinyInt / isFeatured -> Tinyint
    pub available_quantity: Option<i32>, //diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer> / availableQuantity -> Nullable<Integer>
    pub created_at: NaiveDateTime,       //diesel::sql_types::Datetime / createdAt -> Datetime
    pub updated_at: NaiveDateTime,       //diesel::sql_types::Datetime / updatedAt -> Datetime
    pub category_id: String,             //diesel::sql_types::Text / categoryId -> Varchar
}

impl Product {
    pub fn get_all(conn: &mut MysqlConnection) -> Result<Vec<Product>, DatabaseError> {
        let products = dsl::product.load::<Product>(conn)?;
        Ok(products)
    }
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, TinyInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, TinyInt, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Datetime, diesel::sql_types::Datetime, diesel::sql_types::Text): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<models::product::Product, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/models/product.rs:34:37
     | 34   |         let products = dsl::product.load::<Product>(conn)?;
     |                                     ^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<models::product::Product, _>` is not implemented for `(diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, TinyInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, TinyInt, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Datetime, diesel::sql_types::Datetime, diesel::sql_types::Text)`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8)
             and 56 others
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<'_, _, models::product::Product>` for `schema::product::table` note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/david/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.2/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     | 1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `models::product::Product: FromSqlRow<_,
_>` is not satisfied
    --> src/models/product.rs:34:37
     | 34   |         let products = dsl::product.load::<Product>(conn)?;
     |                                     ^^^^ the trait `FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not implemented for `models::product::Product`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
             and 55 others
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<'_, _, models::product::Product>` for `schema::product::table` note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/david/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.2/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     | 1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: Strategies to try: remove fields from your struct and schema until it works, or start with an empty struct and schema and add fields until it fails. You can also check if you have the features enabled to support your `NaiveDateTime` and `BigDecimal` types (which would be `"chrono"` and `"numeric"`.

Comment: @kmdreko tried that but whether the Product struct is empty or it has 1 field like `pub id: String` it gives the same error

Comment: @kmdreko it was actually because I didnt have the feature `numeric` in diesel. Thanks so much, if you wanna create an answer I will accept